# Bug/Feature for pandas where a multi-indexed dataframe filtered by date returns all the unfiltered dates when extracting the date index level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

This is easiest to explain by code, so here goes - imagine the commands in ipython/jupyter notebooks:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

test = StringIO("""Date,Ticker,x,y
2008-10-23,A,0,10
2008-10-23,B,1,11
2008-10-24,A,2,12
2008-10-24,B,3,13
2008-10-25,A,4,14
2008-10-25,B,5,15
2008-10-26,A,6,16
2008-10-26,B,7,17
""")

# Multi-index by Date and Ticker
df = pd.read_csv(test, index_col=[0, 1], parse_dates=True)

df
# Output to the command line
                   x   y
Date       Ticker       
2008-10-23 A       0  10
           B       1  11
2008-10-24 A       2  12
           B       3  13
2008-10-25 A       4  14
           B       5  15
2008-10-26 A       6  16
           B       7  17

ts = pd.Timestamp(2008, 10, 25)

# Filter the data by Date >= ts
filtered_df = df.loc[ts:]

# output the filtered data
filtered_df

                   x   y
Date       Ticker       
2008-10-25 A       4  14
           B       5  15
2008-10-26 A       6  16
           B       7  17

# Get all the level 0 data (i.e. the dates) in the filtered dataframe
dates = filtered_df.index.levels[0]

# output the dates in the filtered dataframe:
dates

DatetimeIndex(['2008-10-23', '2008-10-24', '2008-10-25', '2008-10-26'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)

# WTF!!!???  This was ALL of the dates in the original dataframe - I asked for the dates in the filtered dataframe!

# The correct output should have been:
DatetimeIndex(['2008-10-25', '2008-10-26'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

So clearly in multi-indexing, when one filters, the index of the filtered dataframe retains all of the indices of the original dataframe, but only shows the visible indices when viewing the entire dataframe.  However, when looking at data by index levels, it appears there is a bug (feature somehow?) where the entire index including the invisible indices is used to perform the operation I did to extract all the dates in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually explained in the MultiIndex's [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#defined-levels) (emphasis added):

> The MultiIndex keeps all the defined levels of an index, even if they are not actually used. **When slicing an index, you may notice this.** ... This is done to avoid a recomputation of the levels in order to make slicing highly performant. If you want to see only the used levels, you can use the `get_level_values()` method.

In your case:

```
>>> filtered_df.index.get_level_values(0)
DatetimeIndex(['2008-10-25', '2008-10-25', '2008-10-26', '2008-10-26'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Which is what you expected.

Comment: I see - I actually implemented dataframes in C++ once and I took the same approach with visible/invisible indices for performance reasons and to make it easier to edit views on filtered data.  While, it is not as intuitive as the rest of the pandas interface, I see why they have done this.  That said, what I really wanted was filtered_df.index.get_level_values(0).unique() :-)